# Delete empty directory from Jupyter notebook error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to delete an empty directory in Jupyter notebook. 
When I select the folder and click Delete, an error message pops up saying:
'A directory must be empty before being deleted.'

There are no files or folders in the directory and it is empty.

Any advice on how to delete it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the directory is empty?  It doesn't contain any hidden files/directories, i.e. something like `.pycache`?

Comment: Please can you tell me how I can check that. Jupyter notebook is currently running on localhost. When I look into the folder it doesn't contain any files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, Jupyter itself creates a hidden `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder within the directory when you inspect it. You can check its existence (or any other hidden file/folders) in the directory using `ls -a` in a terminal that has a current working directory as the corresponding folder.

Comment: Thank you. It is creating the checkpoint folder. However it is not being deleted when I try to delete it.

Comment: In terminal do `rm -rf .ipynb_checkpoints`. note that upon revisiting the parent directory from the web UI, it might be recreated.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to delete the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local directory where it stores the workbench files, ex:(C:\Users\prasadsarada)
You can see all the folders you have created in Jupyter Notebook. delete it there.